# Select2 : How to get other response from ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

sorry for my bad english. I just wanna ask about select2 ajax, i have problem with this, i don't know how to get other response from my API.

So this is the response from my API.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vnh3f.png)

so **i want to get zip_code value** when select2 has on changed. but i don't know to get it.

this my code..

```
$(".myselect").select2(
    {
theme: "bootstrap4",
placeholder: "Provinsi, Kota/Kab, Kecamatan, Kelurahan",
minimumInputLength: 3,

        ajax: {
            url: url, //changing by env
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "GET",
            delay: 150,
            data: function (params) {

                return {
                    filter: params.term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data, params) {

                        var res = data.data.locations.map(function (item) {

                            return {
                                id: item.id, 
                                text: item.name,
                                zip: item.zip_code
                            };
                        });
                return {
                    results: res
                };

            },
            templateResult: function(result) {
                return result.text;
            },
            templateSelection: function(selection) {
                return selection.text;
            }

        },



       }).on('change.select2', function(e){

        console.log($(this).val(e.text));
        villText = $("#village option:last-child").text();
        var villVal = $("#village option:last-child").val();
        // console.log($("#village option:last-child").val())
        // var villVal1 = $("#village option:last-child").val();
        villKel = villText;
        villKel = villKel.split(',')[2];
        $("#village_kel").val(villKel);

        var villx = $('#village_land');

        var vill_land = $("#village_land option:last-child").text();
        vill_land_kel = vill_land;
        vill_land_kel = vill_land_kel.split(',')[2];
        $("#villageland_kel").val(vill_land_kel);


           $('input[name="domisili"]').click(function() {
            if ($(this).attr("value") == "1") {
                if(villx.empty()) {
                    villx.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', villVal).text(villText));
                    villx.prop('selectedIndex', 0);


                }
                else {
                    villx.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', "").text(""));
                }
            }


           })

        });
```

picture below is the result when i get the text of value from my API.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwev8.png)

Comment: `var params_formated = JSON.parse(params);`
foreach loop on params_formated.locations and get your `zipcode`

Comment: where i should put it ?

Comment: just after the `data: function (params) { ` and try to print the variable, see what you got.

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: return `json_encode(data)` from your `url` then you can get the json formatted data.

Comment: i still didn't understand, can u give me example code ?